# changing default data directory for sql server after installation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have mistakenly put my SQL data directory in the wrong folder and as such, the system DBs are located in the wrong directory, and hence, I want to move it to a different directory. I am going to move the data and log files for all my system DBs but I would like to know if it will move all the folders under MSSQL or do I need to perform some other steps as well? Please find below the folders that I can see under MSSQL.

[image]

Comment: please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-database-files?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Hi @Squirrel I have already taken a look at the article but could not find anything about the FTData, repldata etc and hence, looking for help Please advise. Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/437a2f3f-a18b-433e-9247-0f77004a49e9/move-ftdata-folder-sql-server?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Comment: Thank you @Squirrel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to let you know the solution to my problem. I have successfully changed the data root directory by moving the data and log files for all the system DBs to the desired location.I also had to change the registry value for the SQLDataRoot directory to my desired location and modify the location of the server diagnostics file as per my cluster requirement. After all this, I have been able to successfully move the folder to the desired location. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: Did you try to use full-text search, is ti working properly? The problems will come not 5 hours after you've done your registry changes, but when the server will be really used

Comment: Well, the full-text search is also working fine. And changing the data directories is well documented by Microsoft too. So, I believe it should be ok. Let's see.

Comment: It's working fine @sepupic .I guess the solution works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move `system databases`, not only you should move the files, but prior to it you should change their paths in system tables by using

```
ALTER DATABASE..MODIFY FILE
```

When moving `master` database you should also change the `startup parameters` in `Configuration Manager`, you should put there the new location of master files.

All this is described in [Move System Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017) article.

Note that if one day you'll need to rebuild your master, it will be put in the old location, so you cannot just get rid of DATA folder. And after rebuilding you'll need to move your system databases again.

Comment: So, the DATA folder would persist even if I change the registry value for SQLDataRoot?

Comment: I never change registry entries. If you did a wrong installation you'd better reinstall. It's simpler to do with the empty server than when your server is working but has some problem due to your intervention

Comment: The installation was right, I only wanted to change my data root directory.

Comment: >>> I only wanted to change my data root directory<<< This is wrong installation. And as you don't know exactly what problems you will have in future by moving them by yourself, it's more safety reinstall the server whan it's emty than encounter a problem when your server is full of databases and busy

Comment: It was just about changing the location of where the actual files are stored, and not the binaries, and I followed the exact guidelines provided by Microsoft. Do you think it can still cause an issue?(The binaries were not installed in this folder.)

Comment: If it's all about changing the location, all you need to do is to move your system databases, any prod database already should not be placed in the default location, but what you are going to do is to manually change the registry and try to guess if smth will not work properly after that. But this just cannot be documented because it's not what you are supposed to do